# If it possible to use `make` command line flags to declare given `.PHONY` target is up to date?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a big GNU `Makefile` that has logically list of parallel tasks to be run. Each task is represented as `.PHONY` target. The tasks are executed in parallel on multiple CPU cores to improve performance by having

```
CPUS ?= $(shell nproc)
MAKEFLAGS += -j $(CPUS) -l $(CPUS)
```

at the start of Makefile. The Makefile logically contains

```
all: ... build ...

...

build: build-binaries check-code-style
    ...
```

and I know that I want to build the whole project after checking it from the `git` repository. And for *that specific case* it's okay to skip task `check-code-style`. **Is it possible to somehow logically run**

```
make --pretend-phony-target-ready check-code-style all
```

**or otherwise end up building everything else but the target `check-code-style`?**

Basically I'm asking if there's a way to do this kind one-time exceptions without editing the Makefile.

Comment: `make -o check-code-style all`? See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Avoiding-Compilation) for the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU Make flag `-o`/`--old-file`/`--assume-old` does this. From `man make`:

```
   -o file, --old-file=file, --assume-old=file
        Do not remake the file file even  if  it  is  older
        than  its  dependencies, and do not remake anything
        on account of changes  in  file.   Essentially  the
        file  is  treated  as  very  old  and its rules are
        ignored.
```

Even though this speaks about files, this works with `.PHONY` targets, too!

So answer to question is to simply execute

```
make -o check-code-style all
```

Which will do everything that target `all` requires but assumes that target `check-code-style` is always update and will therefore skip all commands and dependencies it has.

<sub>(Thanks to Renaud Pacalet for pointing this out.)</sub>

Comment: If you need to skip multiple targets, just add multiple `-o` flags.

Comment: Also note that the `-o` flag will not be passed to recursive `$(MAKE)`. This is documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html